# Unable to refresh Power BI data connected to Databricks due to ODBC error

Tags: powerbi, odbc, databricks

My Power BI dashboard is connected in Databricks.

When I try to update it, this error appears:

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2XEK.png)

Erro on OLE DB or ODBC : [DataSource.Error] ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Hardy] (35) Error from server: error code: '0' error message: 'Unable to continue fetch after reconnect. Retry limit exceeded.'..

I believe that it has some relation with ODBC.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, would you mind typing/pasting the actual error message into the question so that it is searchable?

Comment: Hello! Updated with the error message. Tks